# Why is a returned stack-pointer replaced by a null-pointer by gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, undefined-behavior

I've created the following function in c as a demonstration/small riddle about how the stack works in c:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int* func(int i)
{
    int j = 3;
    j += i;
    return &j;
}

int main()
{
    int *tmp = func(4);
    printf("%d\n", *tmp);
    func(5);
    printf("%d\n", *tmp);
}
```

It's obviously undefined behavior and the compiler also produces a warning about that. However unfortunately the compilation didn't quite work out. For some reason gcc replaces the returned pointer by `NULL` (see line 6d6).

```
00000000000006aa <func>:
 6aa:   55                      push   %rbp
 6ab:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 6ae:   48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
 6b2:   89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
 6b5:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
 6bc:   00 00 
 6be:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
 6c2:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 6c4:   c7 45 f4 03 00 00 00    movl   $0x3,-0xc(%rbp)
 6cb:   8b 55 f4                mov    -0xc(%rbp),%edx
 6ce:   8b 45 ec                mov    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
 6d1:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
 6d3:   89 45 f4                mov    %eax,-0xc(%rbp)
 6d6:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 6db:   48 8b 4d f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rcx
 6df:   64 48 33 0c 25 28 00    xor    %fs:0x28,%rcx
 6e6:   00 00 
 6e8:   74 05                   je     6ef <func+0x45>
 6ea:   e8 81 fe ff ff          callq  570 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
 6ef:   c9                      leaveq 
 6f0:   c3                      retq
```

This is the disassembly of the binary compiled with gcc version 7.5.0 and the `-O0`-flag; no other flags were used. This behavior makes the entire code pointless, since it's supposed to show how the stack behaves across function-calls. Is there any way to achieve a more literal compilation of this code with a at least somewhat up-to-date version of gcc?

And just for the sake of curiosity: what's the point of changing the behavior of the code like this in the first place?

Comment: The nice thing about undefined behaviour is that whatever the compiler does is legitimate.  You have no rights to complain until you get rid of the undefined behaviour.

Comment: You could maybe try `return id(&j);` where `int* id(int* p) { return p; }` is defined in a different translation unit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know the definition of undefined behavior and what it means well enough. It would still be nice to have something like this to demonstrate how the stack works. If I remove the undefined behavior the point why I created that snippet in the first place is gone. Also "can do anything" doesn't prohibit any questions about "why does it do precisely this?".

Comment: Does `int* func(int i)
{
    int j = 3;
    j += i;
int *p = &j; return p;
}` do what you want?

Comment: The point of replacing obviously invalidated pointers with null pointers is probably preferring an early crash over a bigger mystery hunt.

Comment: @aschepler nice solution, thank you :). This actually works, though I was hoping for something simpler, since it was mostly targeted at beginners.

Comment: @KamilCuk this actually works. I didn't even think of trying it, since I thought that gcc would do just the same as with the original code.  Thank you :)
Would you mind turning that into an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: gcc does this sort of thing in many cases of undefined behavior: something that appears intentional yet peculiar.  Frequently there's not a single simple explanation; it tends to happen as a side effect of code in the compiler that is aimed at properly handling correct code, and has unexpected effects or interactions when the behavior is undefined.  Such "why does it do this" questions are often hard to answer, and perhaps not very interesting to the experts who could answer them, and even if they did, the answers might be very hard for non-experts to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the return value in a pointer variable seems to change the behavior of the compiler and it generates the assembly code that returns a pointer to stack:

```
int* func(int i) {
     int j = 3;
     j += i;
     int *p = &j;
     return p;
}
```

Comment: This makes a certain amount of sense.  Under -O0, gcc tends to treat statements one by one, without carrying information between them.  If a single statement exhibits undefined behavior all by itself, like `return &j;`, it may handle it specially; but if the undefined behavior only comes from interaction between two lines that individually could be fine, the compiler doesn't notice.  Of course with `-O` it certainly does notice; in that case the whole body of the function is effectively omitted and replaced with `return NULL;`.